# Automate scrolling for an Android navigation app?

Tags: android, scripting, automation

I've modified an Android navigation app (kind of like Google Maps), and I want to test it. Specifically, I want to do some things like scrolling around and zooming in and out (there are two zoom buttons at the bottom of the window that allow you to zoom). However, I want to do the same test run a few times in a row. For example, scroll all the way from right to left, then wait 10 seconds, then zoom in, then scroll twice all the way from bottom to top, then zoom out after 5 seconds, etc. The problem is that I can't possibly replicate the test run exactly every time due to human error.

Is there some way I can automate the test run? Sort of like a macro that you record on Excel, but with timing as well? Maybe a script of some sort? Basically, I want a way to automate the scrolling, zooming, timing, etc.

Any tips?